# How find this probability of the $P(\xi=\eta)$.

Tags: probability

**Question:**

> There is set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,\cdots,2n-1,2n\}$,and to divide A set of two groups (define $B,C)$ at random,meaning 
>   $$B\bigcap C=\emptyset,B\bigcup C=A$$
>   and $B,C$ of size n each.
>
> and let $ a_{1}$ smallest element in $B$,$a_{2}$ biggest element in $B$,$ b_{1}$ smallest element in $C$,$b_{2}$ biggest element in $C$,

and let random variable
$\xi=a_{2}-a_{1},\eta=b_{2}-b_{1}$

(1): Find the The probability of $$P(\xi=\eta)=?$$

**Ideed: this problem have other answer,prove or disprove**
$$1-2P(\xi=\eta)\ge 0?$$

My ieda: if $n=2$,then $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$,then 
$\xi=1,2,3,\eta=1,2,3,4$
then
$$P=(\xi=\eta)=\dfrac{2+2}{6\times 6}=\dfrac{1}{9}$$
and for  general,I can't works.Thank you

This problem is Jiang Xi National Higher Education Entrance Examination at last problem.

I know @Did like  probability problem, can you see this interesting problem?

Comment: Are $B$ and $C$ of size $n$ each?

Comment: yes,Thank you.+1

Comment: The notation is not very nice. It would have been better to say : $b_1$ smallest element in $B$ ($b$ goes with $B$), $c_1$ smallest element in $C$ etc.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy,Hello,can you understand my problem? Thank you

Comment: http://www.jyb.cn/gk/gktk/201406/t20140607_584877_3.html chinese

Comment: The first values are $\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{5},\frac{2}{7},\frac{5}{21},\frac{50}{231},\frac{8}{39}, \frac{1126}{6435} \ldots$ Does anyone see a pattern ?